# React grabbing JSON response property

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm very new to React. I have a JSON response that is being returned to me VIA WebAPI 2.

I would like to display only parts of this reply, for example if i only want to display the title

I have implemented the following code, but when view title it shows up as undefined

> App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {reply: ""}
    this.callAPI = this.callAPI.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.callAPI();
  }

  callAPI(){
    fetch('http://localhost:51092/api/COM',{
      method:'get',
      headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(responseData => {
      this.setState({reply:responseData});
      console.log("REPONSEDATA-----"+responseData);
      console.log(responseData.title);
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> Update 1

```
    callAPI(){
    fetch('http://localhost:51092/api/COM',{
      method:'get',
      headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    }).then(response =>{
      return response.json().then(responseData => {
        this.setState({reply:responseData});
        console.log("RESPONSE----"+JSON.stringify(responseData));
        console.log(responseData.title);
      });
    });
  }
```

> API JSON Response

```
[{
    "fileVer": {
        "type": "specific",
        "fileId": {
            "type": "specific",
            "internalId": 1,
            "externalId": null
        },
        "internalVersion": 2,
        "externalVersion": null,
        "versionSortKey": "0"
    },
    "title": "1576544 Alberta Ltd._Annual Returns_2012-01-03",
    "extension": "pdf",
    "logicalSize": "47872",
    "sizePrecision": "exact",
    "createdAtUtc": "2019-05-27T15:22:41.510Z",
    "lastAccessedAtUtc": "2019-07-10T21:00:28.029Z",
    "lastWrittenAtUtc": "2019-05-27T15:17:48.000Z",
    "changedAtUtc": "2019-05-27T15:17:48.000Z",
    "fileGuid": "{881D8975-84B9-4A73-9AFF-F0C61C94FE90}",
    "checksumMD5": "24f6badff8b70783697e0052fc4a7fe6",
    "fileMissing": false,
    "contentIsVolatile": false
}][{
    "fileVer": {
        "type": "specific",
        "fileId": {
            "type": "specific",
            "internalId": 2,
            "externalId": null
        },
        "internalVersion": 3,
        "externalVersion": null,
        "versionSortKey": "0"
    },
    "title": "1576544 Alberta Ltd._By-Law #1_",
    "extension": "pdf",
    "logicalSize": "951046",
    "sizePrecision": "exact",
    "createdAtUtc": "2019-05-27T15:22:42.000Z",
    "lastAccessedAtUtc": "2019-07-10T21:02:54.062Z",
    "lastWrittenAtUtc": "2019-05-27T15:16:28.000Z",
    "changedAtUtc": "2019-05-27T15:16:28.000Z",
    "fileGuid": "{F8B54DB0-7E9F-4F0F-8ABA-D03C1DE4FF8C}",
    "checksumMD5": "ffe728ef1a87f0cec7737b6d224bb50d",
    "fileMissing": false,
    "contentIsVolatile": false
}]
```

Not sure what im doing wrong here, ive used Ajax a lot so maybe im confusing what can be done with react and fetch

> Update 2

So it seems that this may be a single object, and not an array of objects.

```
        console.log("RESPONSE----"+JSON.stringify(responseData));
        var arr = [];
        console.log("KEYS"+Object.keys(responseData));
        Object.keys(responseData).forEach(function(key){
          console.log(responseData[key]);
          arr.push(responseData[key]);
```

When i try to access responseData[key] i end up getting a single letter, and not a property from the json response

This pushes me to believe that this is not an array of objects but a single object

Comment: wat does console log of `responseData` displays?

Comment: just ```console.log(responseData)``` prints the JSON response above

Answer (score 1):

you should use JSON.stringify when printing full json response and if part of the object is string (eg... response.title then its ok but if not you can try .toString() or JSON.stringify)

```
        callAPI(){
            fetch('http://localhost:51092/api/COM',{
              method:'get',
              headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
            }).then(function(response){
              return response.json().then((responseData)=>{
              this.setState({reply:responseData});
              console.log("REPONSEDATA----"+JSON.stringify(responseData));
              console.log(responseData.title);
              return responseData
              });

          }
```

Comment: adding ```JSON.stringify(responseData.title)``` still displays as undefined, as for to string, ```responseData.title.toString()``` this results in an error >Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: you are correct, fixed the comment, this should probably work

Comment: I am getting a App.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined now, will provide updated function in original question to track updates ive made

Comment: change `then(function(response){` to arrow function

Comment: Did that, will update above...still is giving undefined for ```response.title```

Comment: The response is array of Json objects or just a single object? If it is array you might want to iterate over it , if it ain’t check if there is object one level above the title property

Comment: I believe it is an array of objects, im looking into how to work with arrays right now. I will update when im able to get some results

Comment: After more research it seems this is a single object, after trying to iterate over the item i find if i try to do ```responseData[key]``` i am given a single letter. Ive added the code up above under update 2